# Android button images radius

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles

Hi i have Button in app and i set button style from shape but when i use images

```
  android:src="@drawable/button_background" />
```

i have problem with radius

http://i39.tinypic.com/33vm3gh.png

my shep file

```
<item android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <bitmap
                    android:src="@drawable/button_background" />
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape>             
                    <gradien
                        android:angle="90"  
                    />
                    <solid 
                        android:color="#eeeeee"
                    />          
                    <corners 
                        android:topRightRadius="0dip"
                        android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
                        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip"
                        android:bottomRightRadius="5dip"
                    />
                    <stroke
                        android:width="1px"
                        android:color="#b7b7b7" 
                    />  
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the button's background to transparent or null

```
android:background="@null"
```

or

```
android:background="#00FFFFFF"
```

Comment: i want like css background-image:url('...') border-radius: 5px; but how adapt on android app?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: i want like css background-image:url('...') border-radius: 5px; but how adapt on android app?